# Shorter way to use SCSS @exported classNames in React (Next.js + css-modules)

Tags: reactjs, sass, css-modules

I have a set of semantic color classes in SCSS, which should be applied to components based on their props. I'm using React + Next.js + css-modules.

## What I Want:

The current code I wrote below works correctly, but I want a simpler approach... declaring a bunch of classNames for every component to @extend something else is overkill! I want to write the extension directly in jsx part. Is there a better (more dynamic) way to do this? maybe inline extends?

Not a valid code, but I'm looking for something like this:

```
export default function Component({ status }) {
    return (
        <div style={@extend %{status}}>
          ...
        </div>
    )
}
```

## Code

This is the semantics file. I import it inside other scss files to extend the classes:

```css
/* _semantics.scss */

%warning {
    background: orange;
    color: red;
}

%error {
    background: red;
    color: black;
}
...
```

### Example Component

```css
/* component.module.scss */

@use "semantics" as *;

.warning {
    @extend %warning;
}

.error {
    @extend %error;
}

.success {
    @extend %success;
}
```

```
// component.jsx

import css from "./component.module.scss"

export default function Component({ status }) {
    return (
        <div className={css[status]}>
          ...
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
// index.jsx

<Component status="warning">...</Component>
```

## Notes

I am looking for an alternative way, so:

- Using a package is fine
- Using `@include` (mixins) instead of `@extend` is fine
- Using `.semantic-class` instead of `%semantic-class` is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use global css to achieve this purpose

Comment: Thanks Man... I forgot the easiest way 